# rudimentary pig latin translator troubles

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a really rudimentary pig latin converter:

```
def pigLatin (): 
    eng = ""
    pig = ""
    movetoend = ""
    index = 0
    vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"}
    while eng != "Quit this program":
        eng = input("input english: ")
        pig = ""
        movetoend = ""
        listeng = eng.split()
        if eng == "Quit this program":
            break
        for word in listeng:
            length = len(word)
            movetoend = ""
            if word[0] not in vowels:
                for l in word:
                    if l not in vowels:
                        movetoend = movetoend + l
                        index = index + 1
                    else:
                        break
                pig = pig + " " + word[index:length] + movetoend + "ay"

            elif word[0] in vowels:
                pig = pig + " " + eng[1:length] + "hay"
        print("pig latin is: " + pig)
    print("program closed")
```

Why does this only work for the first word I input? e.g. I input "test test test" and the output is "esttay sttay ttay", I don't understand why it gets progressively worse? (the first test output is correct but the other two aren't

Answer (score 0):

You do not restart index. Add line:

```
index = 0
```

at first line of the outermost for loop. And there is few unnecessary lines. What do you think about such a refactor?

```
def pigLatin ():
    # work also with vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    vowels = {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"}

    eng = input("input english: ")

    while eng != "Quit this program":
        pig = ""
        for word in eng.split():
            index = 0
            movetoend = ""
            if word[0] not in vowels:
                for l in word:
                    if l not in vowels:
                        movetoend = movetoend + l
                        index = index + 1
                    else:
                        break
                # slicing without last index makes slice till end of string
                pig = pig + " " + word[index:] + movetoend + "ay"

            elif word[0] in vowels:
                # slicing without last index makes slice till end of string
                pig = pig + " " + eng[1:] + "hay"
        print("pig latin is: " + pig)

        eng = input("input english: ")

    print("program closed")
```